# iframe onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, dom-events

I have a HTML page that contains an `<iframe>`. The `<iframe>` is being refreshed on certain events (and I can see the contents of the `<iframe>` being changed, so as far all is ok).

What I want to do is add a `onreadystatechange` to the `<iframe>` so that I can display a "loading" text while the contents are being fetched.

I could not add the `onreadystatechange` in any browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox). From what I found on the Internet it seems to work in IE, but this is no help for me.

I've tried:

```
<iframe onreadystatechange="function();">
document.getElementById('frameId').onreadystatechange = function() {};
document.getElementById('frameId').contentDocument.onreadystatechange = function() {};
```

but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So if you want to show a "The page is loading" message and hide this when the iframe has finished loading you can do something similar to the example below. Note that I used JQuery just to easen up this process. But obviously it can be done in 100% Javascript too.

I also created this on JSFiddle to show you the result. Check it [here!!](http://jsfiddle.net/LaZct/1/)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function load() {
   //iframe has loaded.
   $('div#loading').delay(1000).slideUp('slow', function() {
        $('div#finished').slideDown('slow').delay('2000').slideUp('slow');
        $('iframe').toggle();
   });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

     <div id="loading">This page is currently loading.. Just a sec please!</div>
     <div id="finished" style="display: none">Thanks for waiting, enjoy my website now!</div>
     <iframe style="display: none" onload="load()" src="your_url.php"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm actually looking for a method to display more detailed information to the user. Like "the page is now loading" and "the page has finished loading". The method you suggested is great for the "finished loading" message, but it offers no help for the "now loading" message.

Comment: @Sorin Buturugeanu: Why not just show the message when setting the URL, and hide it at `onload`?

Comment: @Sorin Buturugeanu: How does that not help you? Indeed, show a div that contains that message. And when the iframe finished loading, so in the function load() { }  you hide that div and show the iframe. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Sorin Buturugeanu: I updated my answer. Please have a look and tell me if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Jules: yes, this is the best workaround in the absence of a way to set `onreadystatechange`. Thanks for the time you've put into this. I highly appreciate it!

Comment: @Sorin Buturugeanu: You're welcome. If the answer solved your problem, please tick it as being "correct". : )